# MYSQL ExtractValue from XML returning large blank

Tags: mysql, xml

I am attempting to use the ExtractValue MYSQL function to return a segment from the xml stored in one column of my datbase. Here is how I have everything set up.

Table:

```
    create table documents  
    (  
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,  
    application_id int NOT NULL,    
    content MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL  
    );
```

Insert:

```
insert into documents values (null, 1,
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

    <bookstore>

    <book>
      <title lang="eng">Harry Potter</title>
      <price>29.99</price>
    </book>

    <book>
      <title lang="eng">Learning XML</title>
      <price>39.95</price>
    </book>

    </bookstore>');
```

Query:

```
SELECT content from documents into @xml;  
SELECT ExtractValue(@xml, '/bookstore');
```

The second query returns a really large empty text space. It almost seems like the empty space is equal to what should be returned and interestingly when I use an xpath that should return a smaller result, the blank field shrinks.

I would greatly appreciate some help with this issue and would be happy to supply more info or try anything out.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @ikeWalker I am expecting everything within the bookstore node. I have also tested several other xpaths and they all return blank (of various sizes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not what ExtractValue is for. It's for extracting specific values, not entire elements.

Here's an example using ExtractValue with your sample XML string to extract the price values:

```
mysql> set @xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    '>     <bookstore>
    '>     <book>
    '>       <title lang="eng">Harry Potter</title>
    '>       <price>29.99</price>
    '>     </book>
    '>     <book>
    '>       <title lang="eng">Learning XML</title>
    '>       <price>39.95</price>
    '>     </book>
    '>     </bookstore>';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>     
mysql> SELECT ExtractValue(@xml, '/bookstore/book/price');
+---------------------------------------------+
| ExtractValue(@xml, '/bookstore/book/price') |
+---------------------------------------------+
| 29.99 39.95                                 |
+---------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I appreciate you taking the time to help me out. Have a great day!

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it has to do with the [behavior of `ExtractValue`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/xml-functions.html):

> [ExtractValue()] returns the text
>   (CDATA) of the first text node which
>   is a child of the element(s) matched
>   by the XPath expression.

and

> ExtractValue() returns only CDATA, and
>   does not return any tags that might be
>   contained within a matching tag, nor
>   any of their content (see the result
>   returned as val1 in the following
>   example).

The first text node under `/bookstore` is the white space before `<book>`.